# Suitescript Unknown error: TypeError this.handleChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, error-handling, netsuite, suitescript

I have been working with Suitescript for just over a year. I have a client script running on Save on a Journal Entry. The error I get on Save is "TypeError this.handleChange is not a function". Can someone explain what this could mean with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see it only in Chrome, then it's related to a change in the latest version of Chrome (57). We are experiencing the same behaviour with client-side fieldChanged scripts, which used to work without issues before and work fine in other browsers.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. According to NetSuite support, this should be fixed with Chrome (58). What a headache - I have 3 clients that I wrote scripts for where this error is happening. The scripts now fire when using Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to know without seeing the code, but I'd wager your issue is related to scope.  Check and make sure "this" is pointing where you expect it to.